# Where can I get the strong named version of the dlls for Google .net client lib

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Can anyone tell where I can get Google.Apis.dll, Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.dll, Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll and Google.Apis.Core.dll which are of strong named. Or atleast if I can get the source code of those dlls, I can able to sign in those projects and make them strong named.

Note: I can able to get those dlls from nuget package or in code.google.com, but those are not strong named.

Greatly appreciated if anyone can help me in this case.

Comment: try setting the project to .net version 4.5 those are strong named if I remember right.  Its the 4.0 ones for VS 2010 that are not strong named.

Comment: Home of the client lib is here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

Comment: When you I install the nugget package, all available versions of the DLLs are put into the "package" directory of your .NET project. The Target Framework for your project causes the appropriate DLLs to be selected to use with your compiled program. To the best of my knowledge, there are no other versions of the DLLs available than those that are installed with the NuGet packages.